# Importing csv to heroku postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I succesfully deployed my first Django/Heroku app, and now I only need to transfer my database. It was previously on a MySql db on a Win7 PC. I looked around for ways to import csv into the Heroku db but didn't find anything. They suggest using a ruby gem to do it, or using `taps` and this command:
 `heroku db:push mysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb`.
My database is pretty small, only around 1000 columns and 2 tables, so it would be pretty simple to do it import the CSV files, but I cant find how to do it. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [enter link description here](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/copy.html), you can use the copy command to load a CSV into postgres from you local filesystem. You should be able to use this with your Heroku DB with something similar to:

PGPASSWORD=passwordhere psql -h hostname -U username dbname -c "\copy ..."

Answer (score 6):

Here's a few ideas that should get you going very quickly:

First, a quick and dirty approach:

- Install Postgres on your local machine.
- Import the CSV into a local Postgres database.
- [Push that database to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps#import_push_to_heroku).

Alternatively, a slightly less quick and still a little dirty approach:

- Use the [`CSV reader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) Python module.
- Create a task in your Django app that loads the CSV, iterates over each CSV row, creates a new corresponding model, and saves it in the server's database if the model is valid.
- Run the task via the heroku CLI.
- Once you're finished and you've verified the server database, you can remove the task and CSV from the repo.

Otherwise, [`taps`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps) may suit you well too!

Answer (score 1):

You can import a local csv file as a table in your heroku postgres by the below command

```
PGPASSWORD=<your password> psql -h <your heroku host> -U <heroku user> <heroku postgres database name> -c "\copy bank (ifsc, bank_id, branch, address, city, district, state, bank_name) FROM '<local file path location>' CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t';"
```

Please alter the DELIMITER value according to your needs. The 'E' before delimiter value is to denote that the command contains escape characters, otherwise it wil; throw exception